# Passing Middleware into Controller Returns Error

Tags: php, laravel

I want to pass my middleware into the controller

Here are my codes

`CheckSession Middleware`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->user()->isBasic()) {
        return redirect(route('home'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

In my `Kenel.php`, I add this

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'basic' => \App\Htpp\Middleware\CheckSession::class,
];
```

In my controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('basic');
}
```

But it returns this error

> App\Htpp\Middleware\CheckSession

Comment: Voting to close this as off-topic, as its a typo - `\App\Htpp` should be `\App\Http`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spelling mistake error, **Use `Http` not `Htpp`**

In your `kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [

    'basic' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSession::class,
];
```